# How to dismiss modal view controller from UITabBarController

Tags: iphone

Currently im developing an iPhone Game...When app loaded a login page is seen...when logged in...from login view controller a welcome screen view controller with tabbar(UITabbarcontroller iVar declared inside and connected to tabbarcontroller with interface builder) is presented(using presentModalViewCotroller)..There the first tab is dealing with account ..loaded from accountController NIb and view controller...inside which there's a logout button...when clicked i need to go to login page under loginview controller...

Inside logout button click action method...i had coded like this
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

but on button click nothing happening...

first : parent--loginviewcontroller   child--welcomescreen view controller
Inside welcome screen,in account tab,on logout button click: how could i dismiss the above 
MVC....

can anyone give me a solution as soon as possible...its urgent...

Answer (score 3):

simply try:

> [self.parentViewController
>   dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: ...i had already done so...but of no use...!!...[self parentViewController] refers to the UITabBarController instance..actually i think i have to get the welcome screen controller instance and send the dismissal message to that insatance na??..anyway to get the welcome screen controller insatnce from this account controller whose nib is loaded to the tab in the tabbarcontroller...plss help me!!

Comment: ..oops..i forgot..nyway hearty thanks for your earliest reply..mr marcio!!

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

where self is the view controller that's being presented modally at the moment.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

where **tabBarController** is controller in which we added all the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

i just found it's answer, may be it will help somebody 
we need just one line of code

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```